# Getting the error while uploading Ionic ios app from Xcode App Loader

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic3

This is the error log:

```
An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: org.springframework.spring-core [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: joptsimple; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.commons.codec.binary; version="[1.10.0,2.0.0)"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter [5]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat"
       com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit [10]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.its.asset.lsr; version="[1.4.4,1.4.4]"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.impl,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.media,javax.annotation,org.w3c.dom"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: com.apple.transporter.asperasupport [7]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.transporter.util; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.transporter.util; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat,com.apple.transporter.log,javax.annotation,org.osgi.framework"
       com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter [5]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
           -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat"
              com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit [10]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.its.asset.lsr; version="[1.4.4,1.4.4]"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
           -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.impl,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.media,javax.annotation,org.w3c.dom"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.transporter.transport.service; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.transporter.transport.service; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: com.apple.transporter.commlink [8]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.transporter.foundation; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.transporter.foundation; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"
       com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter [5]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
           -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat"
              com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit [10]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.its.asset.lsr; version="[1.4.4,1.4.4]"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
           -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.impl,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.media,javax.annotation,org.w3c.dom"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.transporter.log; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.transporter.log; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.transporter.foundation,com.apple.transporter.util,javax.annotation,org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple,org.xml.sax"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit [10]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.its.asset.lsr; version="[1.4.4,1.4.4]"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: com.apple.transporter.softwaresupport [11]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat"
       com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit [10]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.its.asset.lsr; version="[1.4.4,1.4.4]"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.impl,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.media,javax.annotation,org.w3c.dom"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: com.apple.transporter.updater [12]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.transporter.util; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.transporter.util; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat,com.apple.transporter.log,javax.annotation,org.osgi.framework"
       com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter [5]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
           -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat"
              com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit [10]
                Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.its.asset.lsr; version="[1.4.4,1.4.4]"
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
           -> Export-Package: com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.mediatoolkit"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.exceptions,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.fileformat.impl,com.apple.jingle.leghorn.media,javax.annotation,org.w3c.dom"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.apple.transporter.log; version="[1.9.8,1.9.8]"
    -> Export-Package: com.apple.transporter.log; bundle-symbolic-name="com.apple.transporter.itmstransporter"; bundle-version="1.9.8"; version="1.9.8"; uses:="com.apple.transporter.foundation,com.apple.transporter.util,javax.annotation,org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple,org.xml.sax"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: com.drewnoakes.metadata-extractor [14]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.adobe.xmp; version="[5.1.0,6.0.0)"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient-cache [41]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: net.sf.ehcache; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: net.spy.memcached; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.http; version="[4.4.0,5.0.0)"

An error occurred while starting bundles for the software update process.  Transporter will try to continue.  Could not resolve module: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpmime [42]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: org.apache.http; version="[4.4.0,5.0.0)"

An error occurred while trying to start the updater service. Exception's name: java.lang.NullPointerException, Exception's message: serviceReferences parameter cannot be null
An error occurred while trying to start transporter. Exception's name: java.lang.NullPointerException, Exception's message: serviceReferences parameter cannot be null
```

Comment: wondering how an iOS app can compile with Java source code in it? "org.springframework.spring-core", "org.apache.httpcomponents.httpmime", etc... are Java based libs, i believe. Make sure you don't have the any java file included in the Build Phases > Compile Sources section

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a proper version if your *itmstransporter* and perhaps you have changed your home directory name or your username.

remove `~/.itmstransporter` by renaming it to old.
`mv .itmstransporter/ .itmstransporter_old/`

**Just run in your terminal:**

`"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter"`